# SSL Enabled on AEM and third party services stopped working

Tags: ssl, aem

Recently We have enabled SSL on AEM and after that we are facing issue to connect with third party services.

For some services we are getting

javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.security.ProviderException: Could not derive key

Any pointers on how to resolve this issue?

Thanks,

Nidhi

Comment: did installing the cert work out?

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue a while ago. The cert file was not installed to the java keystore in my case.

- Ensure the cert file is installed to the java keystore. This command will list the installed certs, check if your cert is in there, you can search by the alias that was used to install the cert.

`keytool -list -v -keystore $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts`

This will help you import to keystore if cert is not installed

`keytool -importcert -file certificate.cer -keystore keystore.jks -alias "Alias"`

You can also search by the alias that was used to install the cert

`keytool -list -v -keystore keystore.jks -alias youralias`

- If you have multiple versions of java installed, ensure java_home points to the location of java where the cert is installed. Also check if PATH contains the same path.